# post form data to controller without page refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

can any one guide me.
Post form data to controller without page refresh in asp.net mvc application using Jquery ajax.

Comment: if you need further help, please post your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [some examples here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). What part are you having difficulty with? You really have to go out of your way to **make** the page refresh when using AJAX.

Comment: yeah i have tested these examples but i did refresh whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "IActionResualt" with "void"

```
  public void Create(...)
```